Coordinates from a drawn polygon
I can't seem to find any website that tells me how to find the coordinates for a polygon in a folium map. My flask app is supposed to allow me to draw a polygon in the folium map and then retrieve the coordinates so I can find the area of the shape after I press the Calculate Shape Button.
Example:
Random Drawing in the Folium Map
app.py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def base():
    map = folium.Map(
        location=[1.3521, 103.8198],
        zoom_start=12,
        max_bounds=True,
        control_scale=True
    )
    draw = Draw()
    map = draw.add_to(map)

    map.save('static/map.html')
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/search_location', methods=['POST'])
def search_location():
    //......


I was thinking do I also need to add some part to the map allowing it to take the coordinates because I had no choice but to ask BlackBox.AI
Sorry for asking too much but I would like an example code of a javascript of the button in html and also part of the python script to retrieve the coordinates from the html page. I am very new to Flask. Thanks in advance!
Welp this is what I did so far
index.html
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="/">
            <h1 id="ProfilePictures">Area Finder</h1>
        </a>
    </header>
    <div id="search">
        <form id="searchForm">
            <input id="searchbar" type="text" name="location_name" placeholder="Enter location name or postal code">
            <input id='finding' type="submit" url='photos\free-magnifying-glass-icon-11.jpg'>
        </form>
        <div id="notification"></div>
        <iframe id="mapFrame" src="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'map.html') }}" width="60%" height="920"
            frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <button id="shapearea" onclick="findarea()">Calculate Shape</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('searchForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting the traditional way

            const formData = new FormData(this);

            fetch('/search_location', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.success) {
                        document.getElementById('mapFrame').src = '{{ url_for("static", filename="map.html") }}';
                        showNotification('Location found and map updated!', true);
                    } else {
                        showNotification(data.error, false);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    showNotification('An error occurred while searching for the location.', false);
                });
        });

        function showNotification(message, isSuccess) {
            const notification = document.getElementById('notification');
            notification.textContent = message;
            notification.style.display = 'block';
            notification.style.backgroundColor = isSuccess ? '#4CAF50' : '#f44336';
            notification.style.fontFamily = 'Arial, sans-serif';
            notification.style.blockSize = 30;
            notification.style.position = 'fixed';
            notification.style.top = '20px';
            notification.style.right = '10px';
            notification.style.padding = '10px';
            notification.style.borderRadius = '5px';

            // Hide notification after 5 seconds
            setTimeout(() => {
                notification.style.display = 'none';
            }, 5000);
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const mapFrame = document.getElementById('mapFrame');
            mapFrame.onload = function () {
                const map = mapFrame.contentWindow.map;
                const drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
                map.addLayer(drawnItems);

                const drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
                    edit: {
                        featureGroup: drawnItems
                    }
                });
                map.addControl(drawControl);

                map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
                    const layer = event.layer;
                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                    const shape = layer.toGeoJSON();
                    saveShape(shape);
                });

                function saveShape(shape) {
                    fetch('/save_shape', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify(shape)
                    })
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            showNotification(data.message, data.status === 'success');
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            showNotification('An error occurred while saving the shape.', false);
                        });
                }
            };
        });

        var polygonCoordinates = [];

        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            polygonCoordinates = JSON.parse(event.data);
        });

        function findarea() {
            if (polygonCoordinates.length === 0) {
                alert('Please draw a polygon on the map.');
                return;
            }
            
            fetch('/calculate_area', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ coordinates: polygonCoordinates })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                alert('The area of the polygon is: ' + data.area + ' square meters');
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }

    </script>
</body>


Yeee I found a way it is just changing some part of map.html stupid of me
// FeatureGroup is to store editable layers.
        var drawnItems_draw_control_a6dd22a64b6a6130aecf47f240d50ce6 = new L.featureGroup().addTo(
            map_9a5fe2b4c0a85f46e0a2eaef8761d87c
        );
        options.edit.featureGroup = drawnItems_draw_control_a6dd22a64b6a6130aecf47f240d50ce6;
        var draw_control_a6dd22a64b6a6130aecf47f240d50ce6 = new L.Control.Draw(
            options
        ).addTo( map_9a5fe2b4c0a85f46e0a2eaef8761d87c );
        map_9a5fe2b4c0a85f46e0a2eaef8761d87c.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
            var layer = e.layer,
                type = e.layerType;
            var coords = JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON());
            console.log(coords);
            localStorage.setItem('Coordinates', coords) //Store here
            /*layer.on('click', function() {
                alert(coords);
                console.log(coords);
            });*/
            drawnItems_draw_control_a6dd22a64b6a6130aecf47f240d50ce6.addLayer(layer);
         });
        map_9a5fe2b4c0a85f46e0a2eaef8761d87c.on('draw:created', function(e) {
            drawnItems_draw_control_a6dd22a64b6a6130aecf47f240d50ce6.addLayer(e.layer);
        });

at this part just need to store variable in the localStorage and then at the index.html just retrieve it by
var coordinatesdata = localStorage['Coordinates'];
localStorage.removeItem('Coordinates');

So yeah I am the one who answers my answer. Awesomely stupid
Just a heads up the output will be like this
"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[103.772694,1.397185],[103.760682,1.33918],[103.885609,1.352909],[103.885266,1.411944],[103.772694,1.397185]]]}}"

so if you dont mind good for you cause u can just clean it in python.

sometimes people answer own question on Stackoverflow. It is nothing strange nor stupid. Now you can mark your answer as accepted, and some time later you can upvote your answer.

output looks like normal JSON, and \" is natural in string which is in " ". And it may need only json.loads() to convert it to python's dictionary.

yeah but that was not working for me so I just regex it well at least I am glad that my question and answer have been seen :')
